# Pigeonhole Principle(Strong Form) proof

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Pigeonhole Principle(Strong Form) says:

Let $q_1$,$q_2$,...,$q_n$ are positive integers

If we put $q_1+q_2+...+q_n-n+1$ objects into n boxes

then
box1 contains q1 or more objects xor
box2 contains q2 or more objects xor
...
...
...
boxn contains qn or more objects

I am trying to do the proof by contradiction

Proof:
Suppose $q_1+q_2+...+q_n-n+1$ objects are put into n boxes

then
box1 contains at most $q_1$-1 objects $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$
box2 contains at most $q_2$-1 objects $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$
...
...
...
boxn contains at most $q_n$-1 objects

$(q_1-1) + (q_2-1) + ... + (q_n-1) = q_1 + q_2 + ... + q_n - n$ !!!
This is a contradiction because by hypothesis we have $q_1+q_2+...+q_n-n+1$ objects

therefore Pigeonhole Principle(Strong Form) is valid

is proof correct?

Notes:
Negation of xor is if and only if

:)

Comment: $q_1 = q_2 = 1, q_3 = 50$. Then I put $25$ balls in $q_1,q_2$ and none in $q_3$.

Comment: Why would it be XOR? Isn't it just OR? As @CuddlyCuttlefish pointed out the Pigeonhole Principle with XOR in it is clearly false. If you replace the XOR with $\vee$ and $\leftarrow \rightarrow$ with $\wedge$, however, I think your proof becomes correct.

Comment: It is not an "xor" situation, just an "or". The term "xor" would mean exactly one of these statements is true, but it is possible for several of them to be true. "Or" means at least one of them is true.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is false. It becomes true if you change "XOR" to "OR" and your proof becomes correct if you replace $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ with $\wedge$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification